# What do I need to change in my T-SQL pivot query to achieve this specific output?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am running SQL Server 2014 and I have the following Pivot query running against a View Table.

```
    (
     SELECT [ResID], [F&B], [LEISURE], [SPA]

     FROM ( SELECT * FROM [EXTRASEXPENDITURE]

     )m

     PIVOT (SUM([FOC_NETAMOUNT])

     FOR [CATEGORY] IN ([F&B], [LEISURE], [SPA]

     ))AS PVTTABLE)

     ORDER BY [ResID] ASC
```

An extract of the current output is shown below:

```
    ResID   F&B    LEISURE    SPA
     1024   210.00   0         0
     1024    0       125.00    0
     1136    0       500.00    0
     1136    0       0         325.00
```

I was expecting my output to be like the table below (with a grouping done at ResID level):

```
     ResID   F&B    LEISURE    SPA
     1024   210.00   125.00     0
     1136    0       500.00     325.00
```

What should I correct in my pivot query to achieve the above result?

Additional Notes:

The 'EXTRASEXPENDITURE' View Table displays the information as follows:

```
ResID    FOC_Date   Category   FOC_NetAmount
1136     2015-10-03   SPA         325.00
1136     2015-10-12   LEISURE     500.00
1136 ..........
```

Comment: did you try changing `SELECT * FROM [EXTRASEXPENDITURE]` to `SELECT RESID, Category, FOC_NetAmount FROM [EXTRASEXPENDITURE]`?, excluding the date column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the unwanted column's from `Pivot` source query, It should be like this

```
SELECT [ResID],
       [F&B],
       [LEISURE],
       [SPA]
FROM   (SELECT ResID,
               Category,
               FOC_NetAmount
        FROM   Yourtable) a
       PIVOT (Sum([FOC_NETAMOUNT])
             FOR [CATEGORY] IN ([F&B],
                                [LEISURE],
                                [SPA] )) PVTTABLE
ORDER  BY [ResID] ASC
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. You have to use a subquery so as to *explicitly* select *only* the rows required for the `PIVOT` operation.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos - Please run the query and come back

Comment: I did and it returns 4 records instead of 2.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos - My Bad, even though we didn't select `FOC_Date` it is considered in pivot source query. Updated thanks for the correction

Comment: @MotoGP Thanks! Works brilliantly!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SELECT [ResID], 
        COALESCE([F&B], 0) AS [F&B], 
        COALESCE([LEISURE], 0) AS [LEISURE], 
        COALESCE([SPA], 0) AS [SPA]
 FROM (
    SELECT [ResID], [Category], [FOC_NetAmount]
    FROM [EXTRASEXPENDITURE]) AS src
 PIVOT (
    SUM([FOC_NETAMOUNT])
    FOR [CATEGORY] IN ([F&B], [LEISURE], [SPA]))AS PVTTABLE
 ORDER BY [ResID] ASC
```

Comment: Thanks. Works nicely!